# Can i call vectorizer.fit_transform multiple times to update vectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm training a [Multinomial Naive Bayes](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html) classifier on a large dataset separated over multiple files. I would like to update the `CountVectorizer` with all my data, but only read one file into memory at the time.

My current code:

```
raw_documents = []

for f in files:
    text = np.loadtxt(open("csv/{f}".format(f=f), "r", delimiter="\t", dtype="str", comments=None)
    raw_documents.extend(list(text[:,1]))

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words=None)
train_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(raw_documents)
```

Is it possible to partially call `fit_transform`, such that i can do

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words=None)

for f in files:
    text = np.loadtxt(open("csv/{f}".format(f=f), "r", delimiter="\t", dtype="str", comments=None)
    train_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(text[:,1])
```

Relevant documentation can be found [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.fit_transform), but I don't manage to fully understand it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `CountVecorizer` needs to know in advance all what all the words in your courpus are, so that it can have a way of mapping words to integers. (It would be nice if you could do a "partial fit" where if it encounters new words it adds them onto the end, but as far as I know this is not currently supported)

An alternative would be to use `HashingVectorizer`; this doesn't need to be fit, as it just runs each word through a fixed hashing function to get its integer encoding.